# OpenMP(C/C++): Efficient way of sharing an unordered_map<string, vector<int>> and a vector<int> between threads

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a for loop that I would like to make parallel, however the threads must share an `unordered_map` and a `vector`.

Because the for loop is somewhat big I will post here a concise overview of it so that I can make my main problem clear. Please read the comments.

```
   unordered_map<string, vector<int>> sharedUM;

   /*
      here I call a function that updates the unordered_map with some
      initial data, however the unordered_map will need to be updated by
      the threads inside the for loop
   */

   vector<int> sharedVector;
  /* 
     the shared vector initially is empty, the threads will 
    fill it with integers, the order of these integers should be in ascending
    order, however I can simply sort the array after all the 
    threads finish executing so I guess we can assume that the order 
    does not matter
  */

   #pragma omp parallel for
   for(int i=0; i<N; i++){

      key = generate_a_key_value_according_to_an_algorithm();
      std::unordered_map<string, vector<int>::iterator it = sharedUM.find(key);

      /*
       according to the data inside it->second(the value), 
       the thread makes some conclusions which then
       uses in order to figure out whether 
       it should run a high complexity algorithm
       or not.
      */
       bool conclusion = make_conclusion();

       if(conclusion == true){

           results = run_expensive_algorithm();

          /*
             According to the results, 
             the thread updates some values of
             the key that it previously searched for inside the unordered_map
             this update may help other threads avoid running 
             the expensive algorithm
          */

       }

       sharedVector.push_back(i);

   }
```

Initially I left the code as it is, so I just used that `#pragma` over the for loop, however I got a few problems regarding the update of the `sharedVector`. So I decided to use simple locks in order to force a thread acquire the lock before writing to the vector. So in my implementation I had something like this:

```
      omp_lock_t sharedVectorLock;
      omp_init_lock(&sharedVectorLock);
      ...
      for(...)
      ...
       omp_set_lock(&sharedVectorLock);
       sharedVector.push_back(i);
       omp_unset_lock(&sharedVectorLock);
      ...
      omp_destroy_lock(&sharedVectorLock);
```

I had run my application many times and everything seemed to be working great, and that's until I decided to rerun it automatically too many times until I got wrong results. Because I'm very new to the world of OpenMP and the threads in general, I wasn't aware of the fact that we should lock all the readers when a writer is updating some shared data. As you can see here in my application the threads always read some data from the `unordered_map` in order make some conclusions and learn things about the key that was assigned to them. What happens though if two threads have to work with the same key, and while some other thread is trying to read the values of this key, another one has reached the point of updating those values? I believe that's where my problem occurs.

However my main problem right now is that I'm not sure what would be the best way to avoid such things from happening. It's like my system works for 99% of the time, but that 1% ruins everything because two threads are rarely assigned with the same key which in turn is because my unordered_map is usually big.

Would locking the unordered_map do my job? Most likely, but that wouldn't be efficient because a thread `A` that wants to work with the key `x` would have to wait for a thread `B` that is already working with the key `y` where `y` can be different than `x` to finish.

So my main question is, how should I approach this problem? How can I lock the `unordered_map` if and only if two threads are working with the same key?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is not clear why you are having a problem. According to the code, all accesses to the shared vector (read and write) are locked, and the map is only read and never updated. Where is the data race?

Comment: My explanation isn't very clear unfortunately. In my comments I write

" According to the results, 
             the thread updates some values of
             the key"

this updating of those values are in my case, the vector<int> of the key that was assigned to the thread.

Comment: If the map is updated, you have to lock it, even if no two threads ever get the same key.

Comment: that sounds inefficient unfortunately, I will probably have to choose another design or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1* on using locks and mutexes. You must declare and initialise the lock variables *outside* of the parallel block (before `#pragma omp parallel`) and then use them inside the parallel block: (1) acquire a lock (this may block if another thread has locked it), (2) change the variable with the race condition, (3) release the lock. Finally, destroy it after exiting the parallel block. A lock declared inside the parallel block is local to the thread and hence cannot provide synchronisation.
This may explain your problems.

*2* on writing into complicated C++ containers. OpenMP was designed originally for simple FORTRAN do loops (similar to C/C++ for loops with integer control variables). Everything more complicated will give you headache. To be on the safe side, any non-constant operation on a C++ container must be performed within a lock (use the same lock for *any* such operation on the same container) or omp critical region (use the same name for *any* such operation on the same container). This includes `pop()` and `push()` etc, anything but simple reads. This can only remain efficient if such non-constant container operations take only a tiny fraction of the time.

*3* If I were you, I wouldn't bother with openMP (I have used it but am regretting this now). With C++ you could use TBB, which also comes with some threadsafe but lock-free containers. It also allows you to think in terms of tasks, not threads, which are executed recursively (a parent task spawns child tasks, etc), but TBB has some simple implementations for parallel for loops, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use TBB's [concurrent_unordered_map](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_unordered_map_cls.htm).

You don't have to use the rest of TBB's parallelism support (though if you're starting from scratch in C++ it's certainly more "c++-ish" than OpenMP).

Comment: actually, **openMP is *anti* C++**: it ignores any recent standards and hence any implementation is always an extension when compilers can implement what they want, rendering portability near-impossible.

Answer (score -1):

May be this could help:

```
    vector<bool> sv(N);
```

replace

```
    sharedVector.push_back(i);
```

by

```
    sv[i]=true;
```

this allows to avoid locks (very time consuming) and sharedVector
can easily be sorted, e.g

```
    for(int i=0; i<N;i++){
        if(sv[i])sharedVector.push_back(i);
    }
```